# wildcard inside string behaves strangely

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I've just started to learn PS. Can somebody explain me below example (the reason for it if possible):

```
Get-Command s*rvice
```

gives hits like `Set-Service`, `Start-Service`, etc. but not commands like `New-Service`, `Restart-Service`, etc.

Comment: That's because `s*rvice` matches cmdlet names that start with an `s` and end with `rvice`. Neither `New-Service` nor `Restart-Service` start with an `s`. You probably want `Get-Command *service` or `Get-Command -Noun s*rvice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're imagining that the `*` represents a single character, but it can match any number of characters. `s[e]rvice` and `s[eeeeee]rvice` and `s[tart-se]rvice`
2. You're reading that `s*rvice` will match exactly the text you type, and vary only where the wildcard is. But you're expecting it to match `New-Service` as if it has wildcards at the start and end like `*s*rvice*` - but it doesn't, it will only match the pattern you typed; the start must start with s and the end must finish with e.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've had the results in my mind split up at the dash. :) Ansgar thank you too, friend.